# How to make transparent part of image unselectable in Qt/QML

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I've loaded a PNG image into my QML code and enabled dragging on it.

```
Image {
    source: "image.png"
    width: 128
    height: 128

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: parent
    }
}
```

The problem is that the whole image is selectable, even the transparent parts which I need to disable selecting on these areas. I even tried to make the `Canvas` from the image, but the problem remains.

```
Canvas {
    width: 128
    height: 128

    Component.onCompleted: loadImage("image.png")
    onImageLoaded: requestPaint()
    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext("2d")
        var im = ctx.createImageData("image.png")
        im.data[3] = 128
        ctx.drawImage(im, 0, 0)
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: parent
    }
}
```

Here is the image which the only red part should be selectable:

[image: image.png]

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the image data with [this method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#getImageData-method):

```
CanvasImageData getImageData(real sx, real sy, real sw, real sh)
```

Then you can check the pixel color values on the click position and decide whether or not to make a selection.

You can find additional info on how to access individual pixels [here](http://beej.us/blog/data/html5s-canvas-2-pixel/). It is for HTML canvas, but the QML canvas should be fully compatible.

```
...
MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: parent
        onClicked: {
            var ctx = parent.getContext("2d")
            // get the pixel
            var imageData = ctx.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1)
            // read the color data and decide whether to select or not
        }
}
```